# Prevent WPF Binding Exception: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor.....' reduces performance

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I wrote the `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="ProductItemContainerStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource ProductItemContainerBaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    </Style>
```

It is relevant only when applying grouping for the `ListBox` that holds this `ListBoxItem`. However, most of the time it is not in grouping and this causes for dozens, hundreds and thousands of binding exception (depends on how many items are in the list). Binding Exception are known reason for performance problems. This binding should expand the `Expander` when code behind selects a `ListBoxItem` and `IsSelected` is changed to true. As you can see the binding is `Mode=OneWayToSource`.

Is there a way to prevent these binding exceptions?

Comment: I had similar problem and ended up using code behind. But I couldn't determine where the expanders were used (dynamic grouping).

Comment: I replaced code-behind solution because it caused worse performance problem.

Comment: Wow really? In code behind you can avoid all of those exceptions all together!

Comment: But it probably pass through all of items. If we talk about hundreds or thousands - you'll see the difference with or without that.

Comment: Did you use `VisualTreeHelper` to get the expanders in the collection? You can attach a handler to clicked event on `ListViewItem` or `ListBoxItem` find nearest expander and expand it. No need to go through thousands of records.

Comment: it is actual relevant only when selected item has been changed. I think the binding solution is more elegant and fits better.

Comment: I see what you are doing here but xaml will always throw those exceptions which is your main concern. I tried helping ...

Answer (score 2):

> It is relevant only when applying grouping for the `ListBox` that holds this `ListBoxItem` ...

Then apply it only then, i.e. use a different style when you are indeed grouping or set the `IsSelected` property in a trigger that determines whether you are currently in a "grouped" stage.

If you hard-code the `Setter` into the default `Style`, then XAML processor will of course always try to resolve the binding. The only way to tell it not to is to remove the binding from the XAML.

> Is there a way to prevent these binding exceptions?

The only way to do this is to either remove the failing binding. You can turn off the tracings under Tools->Options->WPF Trace Settings->Data Binding but this won't prevent the excpetions from being actually thrown when the XAML processor tries to resolve the bindings.

Comment: The first option looks interesting. I will try it.
About the second option: how will it affect on performance of Release Mode? Will it improve performance like without these binding exception?

Comment: No, it's just a *trace* setting. The same exception is still thrown and handled by the framework.